# ASP.NET C# , How to type html in code behind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

How to type html in code behind ? I have this code in html :

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Price</th> 
    <th>Edit</th>
  </tr> 

 <!-- I want a loop here to add the Product name , Price from the database ( To add <tr> and <th> for each product in the array -->

</table>
```

and in code behind:

```
       ` List<string> products = new List<string>();
        string name = (string)Session["id"];
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select id from accounts where 
        username = '" + name + "'", con1);
        SqlDataReader y = com.ExecuteReader();
        y.Read();
        string id = y["id"].ToString();
        SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand("select * from CartItems where 
        Buyer = '" + id + "' ", con1);
        SqlDataReader read = com2.ExecuteReader();
        while (read.Read())
        {
            products.Add(y["id"].ToString());
        }
        products.ToArray(); `
```

so, how can I do that ? , ( make a loop in the array, and add a (tr) and (th) for each item in the array) 
I did it in PHP , is it possible to do in ASP.NET ?

Comment: Yes It is possible :)

Comment: Take a look at the Repeater https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @ste-fu It does not need Repeater, He can make a `div` `run at server` and then create childs easily through code behind inside it. I did something similar in one of my projects a year ago.

Comment: Using repeater or gridview is the proper solution for you

Comment: I thnk that gridview won't help me, becuase I dont want to show the full table, I wanna show only some

Comment: @ste-fu , can you tell me how to do it ?

Comment: Sorry - Not used one for a few years and I don't have a proper computer to hand. Read up about Repeaters and google some examples

Comment: You say tr and th but you probably mean tr and td. Also, I don't see where the Product and Price are; "products" is a "List<string>" so I don't understand how it can have both a Product and a Price. If you add the PHP code you would use then hopefully that would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GridView to display selected columns. And don't forget to set

```
GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns=false
```

Also, instead of writing

```
select * from CartItems
```

Specify column name you want to fetch like,

```
select col1,col2 from CartItems
```

Additionally, only bind those columns into GridView that you want to display.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `razor view engine` to loop your list and render proper html.
[razor view loop](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/razor_cs_loops.asp)
So this code shoud be placed in View - cshtml file.

Watch some [tutorials](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started) and learn what is MVC and how it is implemented into asp.net. The ideal is to split db access from actual views and business logic not to mess them together.

Comment: razor is not working for me, I can't find the array in the html page , ( I have to write the full code, and I can't do it becuase I cant connect to sql ( adding using System.Data.Sqlclient is not possible in the html source)

Comment: OP is not tagged MVC or razor and refers to code behind.

Comment: Can you tell me how to get the array from the code behind? , this would solve me problem